# Mixed entity types. How to create a view of nodes and groups?

Tags: views, 8, nodes, entities, group

I want to create of view of nodes and of groups (group module). Being different entity types I am not sure if this possible. Is there a method by which this could be done?

There is no specific relationship between the nodes and the groups, as I am just seeing them all as pieces of content for the purpose of this view.

Comment: A View can only show one type of entity at a time; if the entity has relationships to other entities, those related entities’ fields can be pulled in to make it seem like two entity types are being displayed, but behind the scenes it’s only one. If the entities aren’t related, and not of the same type, I don’t see how you could use Views to display them (without writing enough code that you may as well have done it manually in the first place). Hope I can be proved wrong though

Comment: I might be able to fabricate a relationship by creating some default content for each group maybe.

Comment: Create 2 separate view blocks?

Comment: @NoSssweat That occurred to me but wouldn't work with the sorting I have in mind

Comment: @MrPaulDriver what exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: @ NoSsswear https://www.drupal.org/project/views_menu_children_filter